# Firebase set up rewrites to pass current user to Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Cloud Functions for Firebase to serve content and I'd like to detect whether a user is logged in or not. I've set up a rewrite in my firebase.json that looks like this:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "getProfile"
    }]
  }
}
```

This works fine and I'm serving appropriate content based on the path that's being requested. However, because I'm not doing anything on the client side (i.e. I'm using rewrites rather than client-side redirects), I'm missing the opportunity to get the current user from a client-side script.

Is there some way I can use a header or a property of the request object so that I can serve different content to logged in vs. non-logged in users in my server-side rewrites scenario?

Comment: Start with this sample - it might get you started with some ideas.  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the tip-off. I'm looking through that repo and seen the `req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')` code...looks promising - thanks!

Comment: Yes, the Authorization header is being used to contain the Firebase auth token, which is then validated on the function side.

Comment: @DougStevenson so using this method would you change all the front end pages to intercept all requests on the client-side and add the header before posting to the backend? Can't I set up Firebase to send the authentication token header automagically for all logged in users?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how it would work in your case.  Maybe put the token in a cookie instead, so it can be manipulated from the client side?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I think I must be twisted in the way I'm thinking about this as it seems far harder than I imagine it should be. I looked at storing the token in a cookie (and I think it needs to be stored in __session to be available on the back end). Ultimately, I think I'm going to have to create pages with client side code (which I was trying to avoid) rather than serve the content from a rewrite+Cloud Function. Hmm...

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Hosting passes along any cookie named `__session` when it calls a Cloud Function. An easy way to do this is to simply listen for ID tokens in your web app and set the cookie appropriately:

```
firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then(token => {
      document.cookie = `__session=${token};max-age=3600`;
    });
  } else {
    document.cookie = '__session=;max-age=0';
  }
});
```

Then, in your Cloud Function, you can parse the ID token out of the cookie and verify it using code [like in this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L33).

Comment: Thanks Michael - so if I set the cookie when the user logs in will all future requests, including those to endpoints that get rewritten to a cloud function pass along the cookie (until it expires)? i.e. I don't have to do anything to facilitate passing the cookie on the client side for each request.

Comment: Correct, browsers automatically pass cookies along. However, ID tokens only last for 1hr which is why the expiration time is set at an hour and we're listening to `onIdTokenChanged` (which fires when the id token is refreshed).

Comment: thanks...I'll code that up and see if it works as I'd hoped.